# Random No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I know this question has been asked thousands of times here and there, but I am trying to figure out why I am randomly getting this error (and by randomly I mean using the same browser on the same computer, or constantly using Safari and Firefox).

I am making a request to a json file stored in a folder of the app. This is the .get code :

```
app.factory('covers', ['$http', function($http){
  return $http.get('http://thewebsiteurl/app/data/covers.json')
  .success(function(data){
    return data;
  })
  .error(function(err){
    return err;
  });
}]);
```

And the app.config part :

```
app.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
        delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
    }
]);
```

The page which is trying to access the json is located at http://thewebsiteurl/app/

I get the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' randomly, sometimes it is working just fine, sometimes it just doesn't so I am pretty sure it is not a server-side issue.

Am I missing something here ?

Comment: `someties it is working just fine, sometimes it just doesn't so I am pretty sure it is not a server-side issue.` you are wrong ... that sounds exactly like a server side issue. If the site sends the header, it's sent, the client doesn't get to choose if it receives it or not, so if the client sometimes gets the header and sometimes doesn't, then it's the server screwing up

Comment: Okay, I am really new to this so I am trying to understand what could be the problem and moreover, why it is being random...

Comment: When you get that error, it means the request is failing the [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) and the server-side hasn't [permitted the request cross-origin (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS).

Comment: so the same URL sometimes works or sometimes doesn't? or is it that some URL work and some don't? if the former, then it's most likely bad server code, if the latter, then clearly the site is set to allow CORS on some resources, and not on others - all this is assuming it's a single server you are dealing with, and you are not expecting to turn on CORS magically from client side code

Comment: So the server would sometimes allow the request, and sometimes wouldn't ? @JaromandaX : we are talking about the same URL here, which is what get me confused about this...

Comment: `So the server would sometimes allow the request, and sometimes wouldn't` - that's what you are saying happens. as I said, a client doesn't choose which headers it receives, a server chooses which headers it sends - which doesn't  solve your problem, but at least you know the problem is (most likely) where you said it wasn't, on the server.

Comment: @JaromandaX : it doesn't solve the problem, but as you said, it helps me understand that the problem is server-side (unfortunately I do not own the server). I really don't know what to do but I am going to look into this with the hosting company.

Comment: I did say "most likely" - I'm not really conversant with angularjs (I take it that's where the $http object comes from)

Comment: I'm also getting the same error randomly. Exactly the same issue. Did you find any resolution @aur8l?

Comment: In my case the node server was returning 200, with additional information about an exception.  This error page did not contain the expected CORS header.